# Operate with a linq predicate if the list has elements

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My question is , how can i operate with the result of a linq operation just if it has any values:

Simple model class:

```
public class Model{
    public string property;
    public void someOperation(){}
}
```

Now a simple main method:

```
List<Model> list...  //supose it has some model objects.
   
list.Where(x=> x.property=="valueNotInTheList").First().someOperation(); //will be a exception
list.Where(x=> x.property=="valueNotInTheList").FirstOrDefault().someOperation(); //will be a exception
```

My question is , is there a way like the null operator ? or something to do the operation only if the list contains elements in the same linq operation.
In fact i need something like this in only one linq operation:

```
if(list.Any(x=>x.property=="valueNotInTheList")){
    list.Where(x=> x.property=="valueNotInTheList").First().someOperation()
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `list.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.property=="valueNotInTheList")?.someOperation();` in case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `FirstOrDefault` which returns `default` (`null` in your case) value when condition doesn't meet for any of the items. Then to hold `null` (do nothing in this case) you can put `?.` operator instead of just `.`:

```
 list
   .FirstOrDefault(x => x.property == "valueNotInTheList")
  ?.someOperation();
```